# Can't call a static function

Tags: c++, qt, static-methods

I declare in a header `traductionCSV.h` the function

```
static QVector<struct variableDurSupervision>
    listVariableDurSupervison(std::string fichierCSV);
```

I write it in my cpp, then I want to use it in another file `supervision.cpp`, so I call it like this :

```
remplirDurCellule(
    traductionCSV::listVariableDurSupervison(
        "../../FichierCSV/ListeVariableSupervision.csv"
    )
);
```

But it won't work, I got this error :

> undefined reference to traductionCSV::listVariableDurSupervison(std::string)

I properly include all the file, so I don't understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post at least supervision.cpp?

Comment: Is `traductionCSV` is a class ? Is function `listVariableDurSupervison` is a method of it class or it's just a "free" function ?

Comment: 'Undefined reference' usually means you haven't implemented the body of the function, or at least haven't implemented it with exactly the right method signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably missing the class name when you are defining it in cpp. It should be like :

```
QVector<struct variableDurSupervision> traductionCSV::listVariableDurSupervison(std::string fichierCSV)
{
    ...
}
```

This rule applies both to static and non-static functions of a class.

Comment: Silly me, that was this !